# Test on method input parameters nullability combinations

Tags: java, design-patterns, service, refactoring

I'm coding a sort of services in Java. It comes to methods having many parameters (with many types as well). These methods must test at first of the nullability of some parameters and the non-nullability of the others in order to dispatch treatments (call of other services, web service call, simple calculation, logging and nothing sometimes...)

These method have the signature and body below:

```
public void method(String param1, String param2, Integer param3, long param4, Object param5, List<Object> param6){

if (param1 == null and param2 == null and param2 == null and param3 == null and param4 == null and param5 == null and param6 == null){
// do something

}

else if (param1 != null and param2 == null and param2 == null and param3 == null and param4 == null and param5 == null and param6 == null){

// do something

}


else if (param1 == null and param2 != null and param2 == null and param3 == null and param4 == null and param5 == null and param6 == null){
//do something

}

else if (param1 != null and param2 != null and param2 == null and param3 == null and param4 == null and param5 == null and param6 == null){

}

else if (...){


}


else {

// ...
}




}
```

the real case is that I'm using ajax call with jQuery to a spring controller method.

```
public class MySpringController{

private MyRepo myRepo;
// some attributes 

public List<String> findAllNames(Integer telephoneNumber, String job, Integer birthDate){

if (telephoneNumber == null and job == null and birthDate == null){
  return myRepo.getAllNames()
}

else if (telephoneNumber != null and job == null and birthDate == null)
{
  return myRepo.fetchByTelephone(telephoneNumber);
}

else if (...)
{
//...
}

else 
{
//do something ...
}

}
```

This case pushed me to expand my question and wonder if there is a design pattern for this.

I wonder if I could find a more elegant way (a design pattern may be) to do these tests. The way in which is coded the example may cause some redundant code... I do not know if you agree with me and if you have suggestions about this ?

Comment: It looks like your methods does many different things. Why don't you instead create several methods, each doing one thing, and taking the parameters it needs and only those. null arguments is something you should generally avoid. Especially for Lists. A List should never be null. A primitive long value will never be null. Testing if it's null doesn't make sense (and won't compile).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was just an example. the real case contains only String inputs. It was maybe a error to put long and List types in my example :( . The real case is returning a List of String which depends on the inputs. It can be seen as a Select * from Table in SQL. * means that all inputs are null and rows put in a select query could be seen as inputs != null in my methods. I hope that it is more clear ...

Comment: No. Not really. Edit your question, and show the **real** signature of the method. Tell us what it shoudl **really** do. If I understand correctly, it should compose a SQL query and ignore all the parameters that are null whan composing this query. If so, I don't see why you would have to test combinations of parameters. All you need is `if (paramX != null) addCriterion(paramX);`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what your code should look like:

```
public List<String> findAllNames(Integer telephoneNumber, String job, Integer birthDate) {
    return myRepo.fetchByCriteria(telephoneNumber, job, birthDate);
}
```

And in the repository, you should dynamicall compose a query based on the values of the criteria. JPA has a Criteria API designed specifically for this kind of use case. If using SQL, here's what the code could look like:

```
public List<String> fetchByCriteria(Integer telephoneNumber, String job, Integer birthDate) {
    String sql = "select name from user u where 1 = 1";
    List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    if (telephoneNumber != null) {
        sql += " and u.phone = ?";
        parameters.add(telephoneNumber);
    }
    if (job != null) {
        sql += " and u.job = ?";
        parameters.add(job);
    }
    if (birthDate != null) {
        sql += " and u.birthDate = ?";
        parameters.add(birthDate);
    }

    ...

}
```

Of course, there are also APIs allowing to compose such SQL queries dynamically (JOOQ comes to mind).

Answer (score 1):

There are several options here:

- **Chain of Responsibility**: You implement a linked list of objects (each of a different class). Each objects looks if it is appropriate to handle the situation, if so it handles it, otherwise it passes it to the next.

**Sample code**:

```
//Handler template
public abstract class FooHandler {

    private FooHandler next;

    protected FooHandler () {
        this(null);
    }

    protected FooHandler (FooHandler next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Result handle (Bar arguments) {
        if(next != null) {
            next.handle(arguments);
        } else {//end of chain, unfortunately no handler found :(
            return null;
        }
    }

}

//Handlers
public class Handler1 extends FooHandler {

    public Handler1 () {}
    public Handler1 (FooHandler next) {
        super(next);
    }

    public Result handle (Bar arguments) {
        if(arguments.first != null) {//the criteria are met
            return new Result("First handler's result.");
        } else {
            super.handle(arguments);
        }
    }

}

public class Handler2 extends FooHandler {

    public Handler2 () {}
    public Handler2 (FooHandler next) {
        super(next);
    }

    public Result handle (Bar arguments) {
        if(arguments.first == null && arguments.second != null) {//the criteria are met
            return new Result("Second handler's result.");
        } else {
            super.handle(arguments);
        }
    }

}

//Construct handler
public class Bar {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        FooHandler handlerChain = new Handler1(new Handler2());
        Bar bar = new Bar(args);
        FooHandler.handle(bar);
    }

}
```

You can implement this as some kind of binary tree as well, if one condition results in two new handlers.